# Best way to duplicate data in the same table and updating a column at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I'm trying to find the best way to duplicate all the rows in a table.By this i mean inserting them again in the same table, but i need to update a single column ***only on the values that were inserted***.

This is to help me write a script so I can automate some work on some clients.

I can't use select * as it will throw an error because of the identity columns but at the same time i don't want to be manually writting all the column names for several tables.

Is there a simple way to translate this into SQL server?

Sorry for not showing a piece of code, but i have nothing at the moment and i'm not really fluent in SQL.

EDIT: I have ended up following the advice of JamieD77 in the comments below this post by moving everything to a table, drop the id column, updating what i need and then moving back as it seems to be the most effiecient.

Comment: List the columns out.  It is the simplest method.

Comment: can always select * into temp table, drop id column and select back into main table

Comment: That would be a good idea. Can I move to temp table, update the necessary value, and insert back in one query?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can drag the "Columns" folder under a table and drop it on the query window and it will paste a comma-delimited list of all the columns.

[image]

Or run a query like:

```
select string_agg(quotename(name),', ')
from sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('MyTable')
```